# Turn on Raspberry Pi 3b monochrome display output

Tags: display, noobs, output

As the title said, I want to switch the Raspberry Pi 3 model b to a monochrome display output.

Comment: there's almost no information in your question. Did you want the output of RasPi to be black and white even on a colour device?

Comment: Yes I do want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

According to this:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md
If in your cofig.txt you set:

sdtv_disable_colourburst=1

then the composite output of RPi is monochrome.